# Why does Step Functions task fails after submission?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I have just started out with steps functions so feel free to ask for details if my question is ambiguous!

**What I am trying to achieve:-**  I am trying to upload a file which triggers lambda function as a task invoked by the step function.

**What is the problem :-** The task & lambda invoked by step functions work flawlessly for other files, but the task after submission fails for this particular file lets call its xyz.sdb

**What i have tried :-** I have tried to fetch the logs of task submission and taks failed in the console

Logs for task submitted

```
{
  "resourceType": "lambda",
  "resource": "invoke.waitForTaskToken",
  "output": {
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST",
    "Payload": null,
    "SdkHttpMetadata": {
      "AllHttpHeaders": {
        "X-Amz-Executed-Version": [
          "$LATEST"
        ],
        "x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length": [
          "0"
        ],
        "Connection": [
          "keep-alive"
        ],
        "x-amzn-RequestId": [
          "xxxxxxxxx"
        ],
        "Content-Length": [
          "4"
        ],
        "Date": [
          "Thu, 14 Jul 2022 02:41:08 GMT"
        ],
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": [
          "root=1-xxxxxx-xxxxxa3e5ed0cb1d6ff;sampled=0"
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
          "application/json"
        ]
      },
      "HttpHeaders": {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Length": "4",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Date": "Thu, 14 Jul 2022 02:41:08 GMT",
        "X-Amz-Executed-Version": "$LATEST",
        "x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length": "0",
        "x-amzn-RequestId": "xxxxxx-d73a-499f-8e3c-f9ca904f94a0",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "root=1-xxxx-4f64750d7ea3e5ed0cb1d6ff;sampled=0"
      },
      "HttpStatusCode": 200
    },
    "SdkResponseMetadata": {
      "RequestId": "xxxxxxxxx-d73a-499f-8e3c-xxxxxx"
    },
    "StatusCode": 200
  },
  "outputDetails": {
    "truncated": false
  }
}
```

Logs for task failed

```
{
  "resourceType": "lambda",
  "resource": "invoke.waitForTaskToken",
  "error": null,
  "cause": null
}
```

**How am i deploying my step function :-**

```
const sdbWholeFileExtractionFunction = new LambdaFunction(
      this,
      'SdbWholeFileExtractionFunction',
      {
        functionProps: {
          code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('dist/workflow/task'),
          handler: 'sdb-whole-file-extraction.handle',
          environment: {
            CLUSTER: cluster.clusterArn,
            SUBNET_IDS: JSON.stringify(subnetIds),
            TASK_DEFINITION: taskDefinition.family,
            CONTAINER_NAME: container.containerName,
          },
        },
        targetTopic: props.targetTopic,
      }
    )
    runTaskPolicy.attachToRole(
      sdbWholeFileExtractionFunction.lambdaFunction.role!
    )
    const sdbWholeFileExtractionInvocation = new tasks.LambdaInvoke(
      this,
      'SdbWholeFileExtractionInvocation',
      {
        lambdaFunction: sdbWholeFileExtractionFunction.lambdaFunction,
        integrationPattern: sfn.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
        payload: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
          bookId: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt('$.bookData.bookId'),
          prefix: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt('$.bookData.prefix'),
          isDiffPackageUploaded: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt(
            '$.bookData.isDiffPackageUploaded'
          ),
          token: sfn.JsonPath.taskToken,
        }),
      }
    )
```

- I have tried visiting this github comment https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9292#issuecomment-667252932, could this be in issue for this particule xyz.sdb

Can anyone guide where to look for status code or error from step function or lambda?
In my opinion, this looks like a problem for lambda with this particular file.

Comment: what is a "step function"

Comment: I suggest you to look on this documentation for a better picture https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/?step-functions.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&step-functions.sort-order=desc :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution, it's not the step functions, in my case, the problem was with file decompression, which led the step function to fail.

In such cases, if other files are working good with step functions, it is better to check for file contents.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need „wait for task token“ integration? You can just call the lambda as request response. Maybe you miss to pass the token back to the stepfunction

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html

Comment: Can you explain me the working of token, and how do my method of wait of `task token` is different from calling lambda as request reponse?

`"Maybe you miss to pass the token back to the stepfunction"` for this i have already mentioned that for other files that same code, sam lambda is being used, its just for this file that i am facing such issues

Comment: You should read the link I have posted. Stepfunctions have different types of Integration Patterns when it comes to call other services. Request response is the simplest one and in your case you will need it. Task token can be used for more asynchronous communication which is not desired in your case. It might be that your lambda fails to execute for the file and you are not calling `sendTaskSuccess`. As I cannot see more code it is hard so measure